# NodeJS clearTimeout() doesn't seem to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, settimeout

I have a timeout which basically kills the process after it's run for too long, however this is only if a certain condition hasn't been met by then. Should my condition be hit, I'm using `clearTimeout()` to clear the timeout, but it seems that the error and process kill persist.

Here is my code snippet; the error is still printed out after 5 minutes even if the `clearTimeout()` is hit.

```
function poll(callback){
    var timeLimit = setTimeout(function(){
        if(log) log("Could not get a response from the command.", "error");
        process.exit(1);
    }, 300000);
    exec("some command", function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if(stdout){
            clearTimeout(timeLimit);
            // Do other stuff
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                poll(callback);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

I tested in browser and it seemed to work in a typical JavaScript console, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong above?

If so, any help will be appreciated. The above is my exact code (aside from the command and error messages, of course) so if anything is wrong it should be visible above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an actual example where the callback is been invoked, but the timer not cleared?

Comment: The above is the code I saw the issue with, the command is an `adb` command which runs over and over until it receives some output. I didn't want to confuse in the question as I'm pretty sure the command is irrelevant, but I can add if you think it's important.

Comment: Well, `setTimeout/clearTimeout` [likely] *isn't* broken in node.js; thus two different hypothesis (holding the mentioned assertion) is 1) `timeLimit` is set to something else before `clearTimeout` is invoked or 2) `clearTimeout` is not invoked as/when expected. (As such, a good next-step in debugging is to rule those possibilities out, as Qantas suggested.)

Comment: Ok, I updated with my exact code.

Comment: Actually, duh moment. The timeout is set every time it loops.

Comment: Hooray! Hypothesis #1 wins \o/

Comment: @user2864740 Go ahead and leave an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleh, late night moment.

`setTimeout()` is inside the polling function so it's reset every time it polls, meaning I can't clear out the old instances. Move it outside of the function and it works just fine.